# Error while deploying MVC application on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have a MVC application build in VS 2012.

I am trying to deploy the application on the IIS 7.

I perform the following steps:

1. I go to IIS server.
2. Sites `->` Go To Default Site.
3. Right click on Default Site and Deploy `->` Import Application
4. Select the zip file.
   and click on next button.

After that is start showing the error...

> selected package contains application which cannot be installed on
>   server level. Select a site and install the package within a site.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new website for the application?

Comment: No, I am trying to add in default website.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error with the import process where it is taking the selected node to import into and not the one you right clicked on.  Try selecting the website in the treeview then hitting import on the right side.

See: http://forums.iis.net/t/1169043.aspx